# How to add additional property in the user profile system?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

User profile service is having primary connection with the AD but if we want to add additional property from external SAP application what are the possible ways?

Answer (score 0):

Make your SAP application fill the ExtensionAttribute(s) in the AD then Map those AD ExtensionAttributes to Fields in the SP Userprofile

Comment: Danny, can you send all steps to implement your solution?

Comment: No, I did this some time ago I recall What I did it, not How I did,   

Besides, StackOverflow is not for letting someone else do your job.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can create a BCS External Content Type for the SAP database and import the info directly provided you can map the user login to the incoming data from BCS/SAP.

Comment: Mathew, please send all steps to implement your solution?

Comment: Search for how to use BCS or purchase Scot Hillier's book on SharePoint and BCS solutions: http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Business-Connectivity-Services-SharePoint/dp/047061790X